# Delete object save in a dict definitely but keep the key

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

What I am trying to do is simple, I have a huge dict like so:

```
class a():
    m=0
    def __init__(self, m):
        self.m = m

    def __int__(self):
        return self.m

b=a(4)
c=a(6523)
d=a(741)
e=a(84521111) 

dict={0:b,1:c,2:e,3:d,4:None,5:None,6:None}

for ele in dict.values():
    if ele is not None:
        print int(ele)
    else:
        print "None"
```

The real one has 4096 elements. Basically, when I decided to kill the object c, I do:

```
dict[1]=None
```

Because I don't want to remove the key number 1, and it is working fine, but the object if still alive somewhere and with 4096 objects it can be a problem on my small embedded system. I can check the alive objects with:

```
import gc
for obj in gc.get_objects():
    if isinstance(obj, a):
        print obj
```

Output:

> <**main**.a instance at 0xb749c96c>
>   <**main**.a instance at 0xb749caac>
>   <**main**.a instance at 0xb749c9cc>
>   <**main**.a instance at 0xb749cc0c>

So, how can I delete these object definitely from my memory ?

**Nota**: del dict[1] doesn't work because it is removed the key as well, same for pop().

I am using Python 2.7, still ...

Comment: Have you tried `gc.collect()` to manually collect garbage?

Comment: Can't u just delete the object and then add the key back?

Comment: @jpp that will only affect objects who are in an unreachable reference cycle.

Comment: Python uses reference counting. If you want to guarantee that the object is freed, you need to make sure the reference count the go s to zero.

Comment: Use `gc.get_referrers()` to list what objects are keeping other objects alive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure you're accounting for the fact that they were in memory before you added them to the dictionary.

```
>>> b=a(4)
>>> c=a(6523)
>>> d=a(741)
>>> e=a(84521111) 
>>> 
>>> dict={0:b,1:c,2:e,3:d,4:None,5:None,6:None}
>>> 
>>> for obj in gc.get_objects():
...     if isinstance(obj, a):
...             print obj
... 
<__main__.a instance at 0x7f4078a34dd0>
<__main__.a instance at 0x7f4078a34d88>
<__main__.a instance at 0x7f4078a34d40>
<__main__.a instance at 0x7f4078a34cf8>
```

Now delete the originals:

```
>>> del(b)
>>> del(c)
>>> del(d)
>>> del(e)
>>> 
>>> for obj in gc.get_objects():
...     if isinstance(obj, a):
...             print obj
... 
<__main__.a instance at 0x7f4078a34dd0>
<__main__.a instance at 0x7f4078a34d88>
<__main__.a instance at 0x7f4078a34d40>
<__main__.a instance at 0x7f4078a34cf8>
```

They're still in memory because they're in the dictionary.  Now remove them from the dictionary:

```
>>> dict[3] = None
>>> dict[2] = None
>>> 
>>> for obj in gc.get_objects():
...     if isinstance(obj, a):
...             print obj
... 
<__main__.a instance at 0x7f4078a34dd0>
<__main__.a instance at 0x7f4078a34d88>
>>>
```

We just lost 2 objects with our delete.

Comment: Sounds logique, I already tried this, I suppose I did something wrong. I will try tomorrow, keep you in touch.